# ASP.net call SQL Server store procedure problem. 

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to call a stored procedure in an ASP.NET page and get its return value. Here is my code:

```
//Something
MyConnection.Open();
SqlDataReader reader = MyCommand.ExecuteReader();

if (reader.Read())
{
    if (returnParameter != null)
        result = Convert.ToInt32(reader[returnParameter.ParameterName]);
}
//Something else
```

Everything is working fine, except that the `reader.Read()` is always returning false, so I cannot get the return value. And the stored procedure is executed. This is confirmed from the server side. There's no exception raised.

What is the problem?

Comment: It's store**D** procedure - a procedure **STORED** in SQL Server (has nothing to do with a store)

Comment: Can you show us the definition of your stored procedure? What parameters do you pass in, which ones do you expect back out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using return value (using `RETURN` statement) or output parameter? If yes then `ExecuteReader` is a wrong choice. ExecuteReader will return the data only if SP uses `SELECT` statement to output data. You should use `ExecuteNonQuery` with return parameter. For example (quoted from MSDN),

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertCategory
  @CategoryName nvarchar(15),
  @Identity int OUT
AS
INSERT INTO Categories (CategoryName) VALUES(@CategoryName)
SET @Identity = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
RETURN @@ROWCOUNT
```

And code would be

```
// Assumes connection is a valid SqlConnection.
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("InsertCategory" , connection);
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

SqlParameter parameter = command.Parameters.Add(
  "@RowCount", SqlDbType.Int);
parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

parameter = command.Parameters.Add(
  "@CategoryName", SqlDbType.NChar, 15);

parameter = command.Parameters.Add("@Identity", SqlDbType.Int);
parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

command.Parameters["@CategoryName"].Value = "New Category";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

Int32 categoryID = (Int32) command.Parameters["@Identity"].Value;
Int32 rowCount = (Int32) command.Parameters["@RowCount"].Value;
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3btz0xwf.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out and the solution is exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

You have to read through the last record in the result set, not just the first, to get the return value.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But my problem is the reader.Read() is always false, even for the first time.